# Run multiple Blazor Apps at same Page

Tags: blazor

I'm trying to run two Blazor Apps at the same Page.
I tested both Apps and they both work.
But as soon as I add them to my htlm page as a iframe I get a lot of problems.
For example the Navigation and buttons don't work correctly anymore.

Both of the Apps I try to add are Client Side Blazor Projects.

Thats how the html page Looks like:

```
<h1>App 1</h1>
<iframe width="100%" height="45%" src="http://localhost:8082"></iframe>
<h1>App 2</h1>
<iframe width="100%;" height="45%" src="http://localhost:8083"></iframe>
```

Both Apps are the sample that is created when you create a new Blazor Project.

My Question is what's the reason why this isn't working and is there a better way to add multiple Blazor Apps to a html page than by using iframes.

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid using iframes.

What you want is not possible. But the good news is that there is no need for it, the component model of blazor allows you to create two separate components to do just what you want. If you want to separate that, you should use two separate projects in VS that come together in one blazor app.